# PHP Variable Randomly Changes

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I have encountered a very weird and concerning problem in some of my PHP code. A variable that I have returns true in an IF statement when it clearly should return false.

```
$pr = $_SESSION['fin_print_printer']; //this should equal 0     
print $pr; //this returns 0, as it should
if($pr == "L"){
   print "local";
} else {
       print "serve";
} 
print $pr; //this returns 0 again, as it should
```

This prints "local" in my script (in between the two zeros) and does not print "serve". With over 100,000 lines of code in my project, I've not experienced this issue yet, and now I can't figure out what is going on.

If I do if($pr === "L"), then it works as expected, but the above does not.

Comment: Show a sample output, if `$pr` IS `0` as you state, it's logically impossible for 0 to == "L"

Comment: Use triple equals there `if ($pr === "L")`

Comment: `==` or `===` shouldn't matter in this case

Comment: As a last resort, my CStatementTracer found here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574614/php-get-file-extension-not-working-on-uploads-to-s3

Comment: You're wrong it matters

Comment: `$pr` is an integer variable. If you compare with `==` PHP will attempt to cast "L" to an integer, obtaining a value of 0, which is equal to the value of `$pr`. If you compare with `===` the test will fail because the types differ.

Comment: Seems like PHP is trying to typecast 'L' into an int, which returns 0. `intval("L") // 0`

Comment: vars don't randomly change, and PHP does as it's told, always. if PHP returns a false from an if, then it was false. check your vars thoroughly

Comment: hmmm, I stand corrected.

Comment: @MikeW You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is trying to typecast 'L' into an int, which results in 0.

```
intval('L'); // 0
```

Change your code into the following so it will take types into account:

```
if($pr === "L")
{
    print "local";
} 
else 
{
    print "serve";
}
```

Or manually typecast `$pr` to a string.

```
// You can also to (string)$pr ("0" instead of 0)
if(strval($pr) == "L")
{
    print "local";
} 
else 
{
    print "serve";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! As another user commented, it is logically impossible for L to equal 0, that's why I found this so mind-boggling. But thank you for the help. Using strval() works great (as with === as was expected).

Comment: @KyleLawrence You can also use `(string)$pr` to typecast it. Just as an additional note. About the L being 0, it's just the PHP Interpreter trying to compare L to an integer because `$pr` in an int.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use typecasting (I did't check it):

```
if ( (string)$pr == "L" ) {
   print "local";
} else {
       print "serve";
}
```

Comment: It works. http://3v4l.org/G6Rg5  Though I might say, using `===` would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Little known approach: You can also do the casting like

```
if ("L" == $pr) {
```

Because with loose comparisons, PHP casts the right value to the left value's type, and as you've already been made aware, while `string(1)"L"` is casted to `int(0)`, `int(0)` is casted to `string(1)"0"`.