# Is there a way to do a "forward trace" in PHP?

Tags: php, debugging, debug-backtrace

I'm familiar with the `debug_backtrace` function in PHP, and really find it useful. However, I have a specific, very messy case where I need to be able to do the reverse - stick a function call in somewhere and have it give me a list of every function that's called after that point until the page is completely loaded.

We do have XDebug installed, and for most projects I use it. This is a really messy codebase, though, with a lot of ajax and php code that's actually created as strings and rendered (I did NOT write this code!) and none of us have ever been successful in getting a debugger to work.

Comment: You can use xdebug to generate a profile, and Webgrind or any appropriate gui to trace where the code goes.

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but I can't install anything on our server, and it looks like Webgrind needs to be installed somewhere that can be accessed by the webserver.

Comment: Webgrind is just a php application, it takes an xdebug profile as input,  and it doesnt need to be on the same maching generating the profile - and it's just one of many guis (one with no other install requirements for a php developer).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I didn't have much time to look very closely at it yesterday. I will take a closer look.

Comment: @AD7six - I took an hour this morning and got it downloaded and installed. It's not exactly what I was looking for, but I think it'll get me what I need. Thanks. If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Lately I only access SO via my phone - take a screenshot of how it helped (or not, though I don't see how having a list of called methods is not what you needed) and accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a [ticks](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php) feature, which can get called at the execution of each statement.

Using the ticks feature, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10574667/433392) describes a class [CStatemenTracer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10574667/433392), which write a call trace alongside the execution of your application.

Might be a starting point.